# Create multi group select drop down in contact form 7

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to create Multi select group drop down in contact form 7. 
I found jQuery plugin http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/sumoselect_demo.html

But when I tried work around, its not working properly with contact form 7.

My drop down items are

1. Investment

   - Residential
   - Schools
   - Retail
2. Leasing

   - Retail
   - F&B
3. General

Is there any way to make it happen in contact form 7. Thank you. 
I am begginer please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using select2 for dropdown with groups. 
[Doc Here](https://select2.org/)

Comment: Is it possible to integrate it with contact form 7. Any demo available?

Comment: If this plugin allows you to modify the code of your contact form, then yes it is possible. I think this is rarely done, anyway.

Comment: I am begginer in this type of coding, could you help or there is any alternative plugn, other than contact form 7 to achieve this.